# How to use ext-gen ID generated by EXTJS in Selenium?

Tags: extjs, selenium

While test automating a web application, I get dynamically generated ext-gen IDs. I tried using xpath but the test cases are failing. I went through different websites but did not find any luck. Can somebody help me?

Thank you,
Srinivas Marthi

Comment: You need to supply the page HTML and tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use xpath during testing automation, rather than id?  Then you will never have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

For automated testing, the auto-generated ID-s of ExtJS are best avoided altogether. You can assign your own static ID-s to components, but now you are basically littering your code with global variables, not good either. Using some ID-s might be a helpful compromise, but you don't want to assign an ID to every single little button.

For ExtJS 4 I suggest using the [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery):

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("panel[title='Orders'] button[text='Save']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been successful with automating EXTJS sites and auto-generated ids, though I do not recommend it.  (because the ids are autogenerated, if new elements are added to the page, all your locators are potentially invalid.)

I'd recommend pin-pointing the precise item, instead of a full path

```
//*[@id="ext-js123"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing using Selenium is to set unique IDs in the Code.

As there is no config buttonId you have to attach the ID for buttons after creation of the button.
In ExtJS 3 we used to set the ID for buttons:

```
dlg.getDialog().getEl().select('button').each(function(el) {
    el.dom.id = 'confirm-' + el.dom.innerHTML;
});
```

Unfortunatly this does not work anymore in ExtJS 4, so I am looking for a new solution also. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As the value of the *id* attribute changes i.e. dynamic in nature you won't be able to use the complete value of the *id* attribute and can use only partial value which is static. As an example, for the following HTML:

```
<table id='ext-gen1076' class='bats-table bats-table--center'>
[...]
</table>
```

To identify the <`table`> node you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

However, there would be a lot other elements with *id* attribute starting with **`ext-gen`**. So to uniquely identify the `<table>` element you need to club up the *class* attribute as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.bats-table.bats-table--center[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='bats-table bats-table--center' and starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python/59637443#59637443)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)