# How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

My application has a lot of selectors that have a dynamic ID inside. When that dynamic ID is at the end of the selector, I use `[id^='staticPart']` inside of every selector. For example:

```
#tab-10 > svg > tspan
```

becomes:

```
[id^='tab-'] > svg > tspan
```

I works perfectly, but I can't figure out what to do with selectors like this:

```
#tab-t0-1
```

where 0 is a dynamic number and everything else is static. I am trying the following, but I get an invalid selector error:

```
[id^='tab-']-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify an element with dynamic `id` e.g. **#tab-t0-1** where **0** is a dynamic number and everything else is static you can use *cssSelector* with the following wildcards :

- **^** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*
- **$** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*

So the most granular locator would include the strategy to lookout for the *initial letters* i.e. **tab-t** and the *ending letters* i.e. **-1** and should be :

```
[id^='tab-t'][id$='-1']
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893747/java-selenium-webdriver-expression-finding-dynamic-element-by-ccs-that-starts-wi/65893830#65893830)
- [How to click a dynamic link with in a drupal 8 website using xpath/css selector while automating through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777770/how-to-click-a-dynamic-link-with-in-a-drupal-8-website-using-xpath-css-selector/59778115#59778115)
- [Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298553/finding-elements-by-css-selector-with-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/50299190#50299190)

Answer (score 0):

You can, at the very least, *combine both "starts with" and "ends with" selectors*:

```
[id^='tab-'][id$='-1']
```

---

In general, though, depending on the selectivity of the `id` values like these, the `[id$='-1']` part might not be significant or distinguishing and something more straightforward could be enough:

```
[id^=tab]
```

This is, of course, specific to the particular markup you are dealing with.