# Can i search an element through By.name, with only partial name?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have been using

```
WebElement strecord = driver.findElement(By.name("Ui_u123));
```

Value can only be located using "`By.name`"

Field is now dynamic but the first 3 characters are always "`Ui_u`"

How can i find it now , "`By.name`" contains ....?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath:

```
//*[starts-with(@name,'Ui_u')]
```

Though this is **xpath**. I am not sure about `starts-with` with **Name** attribute.

It might match with more than one element. In that case you will have to use `findElements()`

**Code** :

```
List<WebElement> strecord = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@name,'Ui_u')]"));
```

As a addition to @HellPine answers. You can write css selector as :

```
tagName[name^='Ui_u']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you try the CSS way `[name*='Ui_u']` ?

Note the `*=` means contains and you can use `[]` for any tag on element.

Regards,

Comment: Note that * is used to match sub string part. You may wanna change it to ^ , as a replacement of start-with.

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight, **No**, you can't use `contains` in conjunction with **`By.name`**.

### Explaination

As per the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) when you use `driver.findElement(By.name("Ui_u123));` the internal *Java Client* implementation:

```
case "name":
  toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
  toReturn.put("value", "*[name='" + value + "']");
  break;
```

converts the locator strategy:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Ui_u123));
```

to:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='Ui_u123']));
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

---

Now, if you forcefully try to use the keyword `contains`, it would raise [**`InvalidSelectorException`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/InvalidSelectorException.html) as follows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
```

---

If you want to implement an approach similar to `contains` you can use either of the following solutions:

- **`^`** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*

  ```
  WebElement strecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name^='Ui_u']));
  ```
- **`$`** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with* (not applicable in your case as the attribute starts with `Ui_u` )

  ```
  WebElement strecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name$='123']));
  ```
- **`*`** : To indicate an attribute value *contains*

  ```
  WebElement strecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name*='Ui_u']));
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)

Comment: I am getting "'css selector' is not valid or implemented searching strategy." exception in c#. Any idea?