# Selenium: How to handle invalid CSS selectors in DOM

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors

I'm scraping a website with Selenium / Python3, the website only uses invalid selectors like:

```
<input id="egg:bacon:SPAM" type="text"/>
<input id="egg:sausages:SPAM:SPAM" type="text"/>
```

*(invalid parts are `egg:bacon:SPAM` & `egg:sausages:SPAM:SPAM`)*

I did try to select these tags with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#egg:bacon:SPAM')
```

But of course I get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException`

---

I also did try using xpath to get my tags, it works with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="egg:bacon:SPAM"]')
```

But my code is based on a home made library based on CSS selectors. Adding XPATH support would require to add ~200 lines of code (without counting unit tests, documentation, etc..) only to handle this wrong and not generic behavior.

Plus, scraping this website is part of a bigger project where only this specific website use that kind of CSS selectors, pushing that much effort for a single website on 10 makes me uncomfortable.

---

I could use something like `find_element_by_css_selector('.foo > input:nth-child(2)')` but it's pretty tricky and any small update on the DOM could break the scraper.

Is there any **clean** way to handle non valid css selectors via Selenium using `find_element_by_css_selector` or am I doomed to use XPATH for this website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all valid. You need to escape special characters or use quotes:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="egg:bacon:SPAM"]')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#egg\:bacon\:SPAM')
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify an element with `id` attribute containing *reserved* characters, e.g. **egg:bacon:SPAM**, **egg:sausages:SPAM:SPAM** you can use dynamic [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) with the following wildcards :

- **`^`** : To indicate an attribute value *starts with*
- **`*`** : To indicate an attribute value *contains*
- **`$`** : To indicate an attribute value *ends with*

---

### Solution

You can use the following solutions:

- To identify the element `<input id="egg:bacon:SPAM" type="text"/>`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='egg'][id*='bacon'][id$='SPAM']")
  ```
- To identify the element `<input id="egg:sausages:SPAM:SPAM" type="text"/>`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='egg'][id*='sausages'][id$='SPAM']")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python/59637443#59637443)
- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)

Comment: Super nice, it works. But I have few inputs like `egg:bacon:SPAM` & `egg:bacon:SPAM:SPAM` on the same page. As I understand your anwser it uses _a kind of regex expression_ (`^`, `*`, `$`) and I fear the example I gave in this comment would not be supported with this method. Also do you have a doc or keyword so I can find doc about this? (_+1 anyway_)

Comment: @Arount `^`, `*` and `$` aren't _regex expression_ as such :) but **wildcards** used with _cssSelectors_. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, very nice to know and super hepful. I will still validate Sers' anwser because it's less verbose (and a `replace(':', '\\:')` at the right place do the job) but I keep my upvote because it's very good answer (and yeah, wildcards.. ooops :D)

Comment: Just for record, I just had a situation where I had to use your wildcards, epic.

Comment: @Arount This answer is based on best practices which you have to adapt in the longer run.

Comment: I will stop commenting after that because it does not add quality to your answer but yea, it's a game changer for me. Very nice life improvement. 10/10 will use everyday from now