# How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using selenium with python,now I want to locate an element by part of its id name,what can I do?

For example,now I've already located a item by id name **coption5** :

```
sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_id("coption5")
```

Is there anyway I can locate this element only by using **coption**?

Comment: Use XPATH's "contains" method: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#6

Comment: Use css: `[id^="coption"]`

Comment: @Guy This question is all about locators _Xpath_ and _Css_, any reason why you want to hide the question from _Xpath_ and _Css_ contributors removing those tags?

Comment: @DebanjanB Using xpath and css_selector is the solution, not the question.

Comment: @Guy So what do you feel the question was all about :) Does Selenium have any other way other then _Css_ and _Xpath_

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, it has https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: @Guy I'm sorry, I'm not getting your logic here. Anyway, please try to assist the _New contributors_ rather then reducing the visibility of the questions asked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,can you help me with this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653599/how-to-locate-element-by-class-name-and-specific-attribute-name-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To find the element which you have located with:

```
sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_id("coption5")
```

To locate this element only by using **coption** you can use can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'coption')]")
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `contains()`:

  ```
  sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'coption')]")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `^` (wildcard of starts-with):

  ```
  sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id^='coption']")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `*` (wildcard of contains):

  ```
  sixth_item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id*='coption']")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on dynamic CssSelectors in:

- [How to get selectors with dynamic part inside using Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)
- [Java Selenium webdriver expression finding dynamic element by ccs that starts with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893747/java-selenium-webdriver-expression-finding-dynamic-element-by-ccs-that-starts-wi/65893830#65893830)
- [How to click a dynamic link with in a drupal 8 website using xpath/css selector while automating through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777770/how-to-click-a-dynamic-link-with-in-a-drupal-8-website-using-xpath-css-selector/59778115#59778115)
- [Finding elements by CSS selector with ChromeDriver (Selenium) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298553/finding-elements-by-css-selector-with-chromedriver-selenium-in-python/50299190#50299190)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,but in my situation it doesn't work now.I'll keep trying!

Comment: Sir can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653599/how-to-locate-element-by-class-name-and-specific-attribute-name-at-the-same-time

Comment: It is so useful!Thank you so much!