# How to locate element by class name and specific attribute name at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using selenim python,and want to locate the following element:

```
<div id="coption5" class="copt" style="display: block;">
```

I need both the class name **'copt'** and style value **"display: block;"**,is there any way I can locate this element with both class name and attribute value at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your failing attempts ? Show us your code

Comment: Read the documentation, and try to figure it out first.

Comment: Use css: `.copt[style="display: block;"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase considering the *style* value **`display: block;`** is mandatory you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.copt[id^='coption']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='copt' and starts-with(@id, 'coption')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Can I code like this: element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='copt' and @style='"display: block;"']")))

Comment: @William `style='"display: block;"` will be taken taken care by `visibility_of_element_located`. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi sir ,can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654630/selenium-python-failed-to-locate-descendant-element-in-xpath

Comment: Hi Sir,when use element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='copt' and starts-with(@id, 'coption')]")))
I received a message: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)