# How to locate the descendant label elements using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium python to try to find out all the descendant  under the first div, so I used this code:

```
label_element =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='display:block']/descendant::label")
```

But get an empty list [].

```
<div id="coption5" class="copt" style="display: block;">
<div style="height:100%;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;">
<div class="coptw">
<div style="width:100%;height:49px;border-bottom:1px solid #888">
<b class="cpopdish">SUPREME CALZONE (M)  10.99</b>
<b class="cpopmodifi gray" data-iid="0" style="font-weight: normal;">
<i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Special Request</b><b class="cpopprice">10.99</b></div>
<div class="comain" style="right: 0px;">
<div class="crow" grp="0" grpname="">

<label class="label0" cid="5" style="">
<input type="radio" name="0" coname="BF PEPPERONI(M)" sname="" price="0.00" value="2">BF PEPPERONI(M)<b class="ip">0.00</b>
</label>
<label class="label0" cid="5"><input type="radio" name="0" coname="BLACK OLIVES(M)" sname="" price="0.00" value="3">BLACK OLIVES(M)<b class="ip">0.00</b>
</label>
<label class="label0" cid="5"><input type="radio" name="0" coname="CHICKEN(M)" sname="" price="1.00" value="4">CHICKEN(M)<b class="ip">1.00</b>
</label>
<div style="clear:both"></div></div>
</div><a class="ocancel" data-cid="5" data-grps="0"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel</a></div></div>
```

Any friend know how to use Xpath or Css selector to locate all the label tag?

this first part of my code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='display:block']")
```

Can locate the first div element successfully so I think maybe there is nothing wrong with the visibility issues. The label tag is inside the first div tag, label are the descendant of the first div.

So any friend can help?

Answer (score 1):

To extract all the text items from the `<label>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)  and *Python* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.copt[id^='coption'] div.comain>div.crow>label")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='copt' and starts-with(@id, 'coption')]//div[@class='comain']/div[@class='crow']/label")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct xpath that will find all 3 labels.

```
//div[@style='display: block;']/descendant::label
```

[image]