# How to get a table with dynamic id using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to grab a table from this page https://www.holidayfrancedirect.co.uk/holiday-rentals/RG007075/index.htm and other similar pages.

The table in question has a dynamic id `table-XXXX` where X is a different number each time the page loads.

The table has the following attributes:

```py
class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack table-bordered table-centered rates-availability-table"

data-tablesaw-mode="stack"
```

I have tried the following variants to locate this table (having consulted this post [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python)) but nothing seems to work.

```py
find_elements_by_css_selector("[id*='tab']")

find_elements_by_css_selector("[class*='tablesaw']")

find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-tablesaw-mode*='stack']")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) are [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) elements so to print the values you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.holidayfrancedirect.co.uk/holiday-rentals/RG007075/index.htm')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.tablesaw.tablesaw-stack.table-bordered.table-centered.rates-availability-table"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.holidayfrancedirect.co.uk/holiday-rentals/RG007075/index.htm')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tablesaw tablesaw-stack table-bordered table-centered rates-availability-table']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Start Date End Date 3 Nights 4 Nights 5 Nights 6 Nights 7 Nights
  28 Mar 2020 1 May 2020 £225 £300 £350 £410 £470
  2 May 2020 26 Jun 2020 £250 £330 £400 £460 £530
  27 Jun 2020 3 Jul 2020 - - - - £675
  4 Jul 2020 10 Jul 2020 - - - - £920
  11 Jul 2020 14 Aug 2020 - - - - £985
  15 Aug 2020 21 Aug 2020 - - - - £920
  22 Aug 2020 28 Aug 2020 - - - - £675
  29 Aug 2020 31 Oct 2020 - - - - £470
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. But you can use their API to load the table.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.holidayfrancedirect.co.uk/holiday-rentals/RG007075/index.htm'
rates_url = 'https://www.holidayfrancedirect.co.uk/api/property-rates/{property_id}/2020'
property_id = url.split('/')[-2]

data = requests.get(rates_url.format(property_id=property_id)).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data['ratesHtml'], 'html.parser')

# print table to screen:
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td, th')]
    print(('{:<15}'*7).format(*tds))
```

Prints:

```
Start Date     End Date       3 Nights       4 Nights       5 Nights       6 Nights       7 Nights       
28 Mar 2020    1 May 2020     £225           £300           £350           £410           £470           
2 May 2020     26 Jun 2020    £250           £330           £400           £460           £530           
27 Jun 2020    3 Jul 2020     -              -              -              -              £675           
4 Jul 2020     10 Jul 2020    -              -              -              -              £920           
11 Jul 2020    14 Aug 2020    -              -              -              -              £985           
15 Aug 2020    21 Aug 2020    -              -              -              -              £920           
22 Aug 2020    28 Aug 2020    -              -              -              -              £675           
29 Aug 2020    31 Oct 2020    -              -              -              -              £470
```