# Selenium: How can I get the checked checkbox from nested input by div and label?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Html block first:

```
<div class="formClass" style="line-height: 18px; display: block;">

    <label id="randomId_34_30078" style="display: none; width:47%; margin-right: 5px;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="30078" disabled="">First Text
    </label>

    <label id="randomId_34_30077" style="display: none; width:47%; margin-right: 5px;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="30077" disabled="">Second Text
    </label>
    
    <label id="randomId_32_30078" style="display: inline-block; width:47%; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 10%; float: left;">

             <input type="checkbox" value="30078" disabled="" checked="">

        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 90%; float: right;">
            First Text
        </div>
    </label>

    <label id="randomId_32_30077" style="display: inline-block; width:47%; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 10%; float: left;">
            
            <input type="checkbox" value="30077" disabled="">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 90%; float: right;">
            Second Text
        </div>
    </label>

</div>
```

I'd like to get the checkbox of which the value is "30078" in the above HTML section.
The id of labels are random, also the value of the input/checkbox. It's a legacy project. I can't modify the structure.

I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("formClass"))
                    .findElement(By.xpath("//label//div[contains(text(), 'First Text')]"))
```

but this gets two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the checkbox, you need to write the XPATH for the  tag.

If you need to write the xpath for below :

```
 <label id="randomId_34_30078" style="display: none; width:47%; margin-right: 5px;">
    <input type="checkbox" value="30078" disabled="">First Text
</label>
```

you can use

```
//div[@class="formClass"]/label/input[contains(text(),"First Text")]
```

Comment: findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='formClass']//label//div[contains(text(),'First Text')]//preceding-sibling::div//input"))
Thanks. I tried this. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are two elements with attribute `value="30078"` among them only one is visible while the other one contains the attribute **`style="display: none;`**.

So to get the visible/interactable checkbox with *value* attribute set as **30078** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[id^='randomId'] input[value='30078']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@id, 'randomId')]//input[@value='30078']")));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python/59637443#59637443)

Comment: Thanks. The id and the value of the label and input are random, I can get the element by this xpath.