# Is there a way to select an item on a webpage with Selenium with no unique ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

My objective is to open a webpage, and click the app button for a specific app, like Anaplan. In the past, I've used get element by CSS selector with the combination of class, and ID, [as shown in this past post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637048/how-to-find-element-by-part-of-its-id-name-in-selenium-with-python).

```
first_item = driver.find_element_by_id("anaplan")
```

I've come across a webpage where the buttons seem to have literally no ID whatsoever, or unique values:

[image]

[image]

HTML output of the Anaplan App button:

```
<a
  aria-label="launch app Anaplan"
  class="chiclet a--no-decoration"
  data-se="app-card"
  href="https://gartner.okta.com/home/anaplan/0oaforg08lyATdLuw4x6/2487"
  draggable="true"
  ><article class="chiclet--article">
    <button
      class="chiclet--action"
      tabindex="0"
      aria-label="Settings for Anaplan"
      data-se="app-card-settings-button"
    >
      <svg
        class="chiclet--action-kebab"
        width="20"
        height="4"
        viewBox="0 0 20 4"
        fill="#B7BCC0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="10" cy="2" r="2"></circle>
        <circle cx="18" cy="2" r="2"></circle>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <section class="chiclet--main" data-se="app-card-main">
      <img
        class="chiclet--main-logo"
        src="https://ok11static.oktacdn.com/fs/bcg/4/gfs1ev15ab63zqgZ91d8"
        alt="Anaplan logo"
      />
    </section>
    <footer class="chiclet--footer" data-se="app-card-footer">
      <o-tooltip content="Anaplan" position="bottom" class="hydrated"
        ><div slot="content"></div>
        <div aria-describedby="o-tooltip-0">
          <h1 class="chiclet--app-title" data-se="app-card-title">Anaplan</h1>
        </div>
      </o-tooltip>
    </footer>
  </article>
</a>
```

I grabbed the Xpath of the Anaplan button, which shows the following:

```
/html[@class='hydrated wf-proximanova-n4-inactive wf-
inactive']/body[@class='default']/div[@id='root']
/div[@class='enduser-app ']/section[@class='content-frame']
/main[@class='main-container has-top-bar']/div[@class='dashboard--main']/section[@id='main- 
content']/section[@class='chiclet-area']
/section[@class='chiclet-grid--container']
/section/section[@class='chiclet-grid section-appear-done section-enter-done']
/a[@class='chiclet a--no-decoration'][1]/article[@class='chiclet--article']
```

The only differences between apps is the number in the bracket:
`/a[@class='chiclet a--no-decoration'][1]`, where 1 seems to be Anaplan, 3 is G Drive, and so on. Is there a way to select elements such as this where there appears to be no unique identifier at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the first button you can use one of the following `xpath`s `//a[@aria-label='launch app Anaplan']` or `//a[contains(@href,'anaplan')]` and there are many other unique combinations.  The same can be done with `css selectors`
Similarly to the above there are several combinations for all the other navigation buttons you provided here.
In case the element located inside `<iframe>` you have to switch to that `<iframe>` first and get out of it after that.
Locate the `<iframe>` with
`iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='iframeName']")`  or whatever locator that it matches
Then `switch_to` the `<iframe>`:
`driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`
If after that you need to continue anywhere out of the `<iframe>` switch out of it with
`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: //a[contains(@href,'anaplan')] worked perfectly. However, it does not seem to work on another page, when that contains an iframe, as shown in the below paste.//a[contains(@href,'401068')] for example returns an error as unable to find the element, even though the href in the HTML definitely has that in it
https://pastebin.com/D5Fzn6hu

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly to `<iframe>` issue

Answer (score 1):

It is possible both with xpath and css.
Example of `xpath`:

Anaplan:

```
//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Anaplan')]/article/button
```

Or:

```
//button[contains(@aria-label, 'Settings for Anaplan')]
```

Spam Quarantine:

```
//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Spam Quarantine')]
```

G-suite

```
//a[contains(@aria-label, 'G Suite Drive')]
```

The main idea is that you can find an element by writing a partial name of an attribute.

**Update:**

If an element is located inside an iframe, you should wait for it to load and switch to it. Selenium has very convenient method for it: **frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[data-testid=shell-content]")))
```

After switching to iframe you work with elements inside it.

Comment: All of these worked. But don't seem to work on an iframe either, similar to the other solutions. Is an iframe different somehow? 
pastebin.com/D5Fzn6hu