# I am not able to interact with an Element that is inside a #shadow-root and has an <iframe> tag on it

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, shadow-dom

[Page source:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqs7m.png)

I am using selenium with java.
To access the shadow-root, I am using JavascripExecutor (document.shadowRoot.querySelector)

I am able to interact with other elements inside of the page. but I am not able to get inside of this iframe and paste what I want over the text box.

this is how I am interacting with other elements :

WebElement selectSubError1 = (WebElement) jsExecutor.executeScript("return document.querySelector");
((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", selectSubError1);

please if you know the resolution of it, comment bellow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch to the iframe as if it's a separate window:

https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

```
driver.switchTo().frame("a077aa5e");
```

More iframe details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67383631/1387701

Comment: Hi, thank you, but that is not the problem.

Please open the link where it says "Page Source" to see the picture of my code.

The problem is to switch to the frame inside shadow root. it is not a normal frame. 
Change between frames I am already aware.

Answer (score 0):

use selector hub plug in for the browser.
It will save lot's of time. I had a similar situation.
iframe inside shadow-root.

CSS selector will help you to resolve this, try this plug-in it will save allot of time.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub-xpath-plugin/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh

```
//This Element is inside single shadow DOM.
String cssSelectorForHost1 = "html > div:nth-child(1)";
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement shadowDomHostElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html > div:nth-child(1)"));
WebElement last = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowDomHostElement);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.switchto().form(last.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ra-move-in.ra-new-in.ra-flag-in.ra-shown.ra-pin-ac")));
```