# Python Selenium , how to access to input with xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to get to "input" so that I can enter the values, knowing that the value of the ID is constantly changing

```
<div>
    <idms-error-wrapper {^error-type}="errorType" {^idms-error-wrapper-classes}="idmsErrorWrapperClasses"

            <div class=" form-element ">
                <input errors="{errors}" {^has-errors}="hasErrors" {$value}="value"
                       {$aria-required}="isRequired" type="text"
                       class="form-cell form-textbox form-textbox-text form-field"
                       id="input-1647425309700-0" value="" aria-required="true">
            </div>
            
    </idms-error-wrapper>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `1647425309700` or `1647425309700-0` is variable here you can use something like this:

```py
input_id = 1647425309700
input_xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'"+ str(input_id) +"')]"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,input_xpath)
```

Comment: the value of the ID is constantly changing ،، When you open the browser

Comment: So, you meant it is not known value but dynamically generated by the page itself so you can not know it?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: In this case you will not be able to locate this element based on it id. You have to find some other, fixed and stable locator. Can you provide a link to the page where you working so we can help finding the better locator?

Answer (score 0):

The *`<id>`* attribute of the `<input>` tag, i.e. **`input-1647425309700-0`** is dynamically generated and will change everytime you would access the page afresh. So identify the desired element you can use either of the the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *css_selector*:

  ```
  input.form-cell.form-textbox.form-textbox-text.form-field[id^='input'][aria-required='true'][value]
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  //input[@class='form-cell form-textbox form-textbox-text form-field' and starts-with(@id, 'input')][@aria-required='true' and @value]
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to find element by part of its id name in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637443/7429447)