# How to check ext-gen element exists in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, extjs, element

```
 def conformation():
  try:
    conf_btn= driver.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen1315")
    #Error_alert
    err_alert=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']")
    err_alert.click()
    print("success")
    return 0   
  except NoSuchElementException:
    print ("conformation div element not found")
    return 1
```

In this function I need to check whether this `ext-gen1315` div element is present, then click that `err_alert` button, else return 1.

Always I am getting `NoSuchElementException` only. While running this I could see this element in browser's inspect elements. I don't know where I made mistake.

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']"}

But i could see the element while inspecting
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use `find_elements`, so that you don't raise the unnecessary expections.

```
def conformation():
    if (len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']"))>0):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']").click()
        print("success")
        return 0
    else:
        print("conformation div element not found")
        return 1
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
conf_btn= driver.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen1315")
if conf_btn:
    err_alert=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']")
    err_alert.click()
    print("success")
    return 0 
else: 
    return 1
```

Comment: I believe driver.find_element will raise an exception if the element is not there

Comment: It's likely. I sometimes confuse `selenium`'s behaviour with `BeautifulSoup`'s. I know this is one way to make it work with bs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of alert box this is but there is this driver method that is more elegant if its a standard alert. Probably wont work if this is a modal.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    driver.switch_to_alert.accept()
    return 0
except TimeoutException:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
NoSuchElementException
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to locate the desired element.

---

### Ext JS

[Ext JS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) is a JavaScript framework for building data-intensive, cross-platform web and mobile applications for any modern device.

---

### This usecase

There are two issues with the line of code:

```
conf_btn= driver.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen1315")
```

- First of all as the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()`.
- Next, the suffix in the value of the *id* attribute changes i.e. dynamic in nature you won't be able to use the complete value of the *id* attribute.

---

### Solution

As the value of the *id* attribute is dynamic in nature you can use only partial value which is static. As an example, for the following HTML:

```
<div id="ext-gen1315" class="bats-table"></div>
```

To identify the <`div`> node you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  conf_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  conf_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

However, there would be a lot other elements with *id* attribute starting with **`ext-gen`**. So to uniquely identify the `<table>` element you need to club up the *class* attribute as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bats-table[id^='ext-gen']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bats-table' and starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')]")))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Element has ID in inspection mode, but not in raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464685/element-has-id-in-inspection-mode-but-not-in-raw-html/60470649#60470649)
- [How to use ext-gen ID generated by EXTJS in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014376/how-to-use-ext-gen-id-generated-by-extjs-in-selenium/60470693#60470693)

Comment: i am getting no such element exception 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='x-btn x-unselectable rp-btn-shadow rp-important-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon' and @id='button-1016']"}